# Syntax error on awk call with if statement, works without

Tags: awk

I've got a simple awk line in a makefile that prints out every line of a file.

```
awk '{print $0}' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c
```

It works fine when I run make. But there is some lines in foo.h that I don't want carried over to bar.c. So I modified the awk.

```
awk '{if ($0 != "#include \"foobar.h\"") {print $0}}' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c
```

But I get a syntax error back.

```
awk '{if ( != "#include \"foobar.h\"") {print }}' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c
awk: {if ( != "#include \"foobar.h\"") {print }}
awk:       ^ syntax error
```

I'm guessing its a simple mistake on my part, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: do you know that your first `awk` script is useless?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `cat ../foo/foo.h | grep -v '#include "foobar.h"' | grep -v '#include "foobar2.h"' >> bar.c` suffice? No programming and no escaping is much less maintenance.

Comment: Why `awk` when a simple `sed` will do? `sed '/#include "foobar.h"/d' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c`.

Comment: And if you really want `awk` you can `awk '!/#include "foobar.h"/' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a makefile, you need to double the dollar signs.

```
    awk '{if ($$0 != "#include \"foobar.h\"") {print $$0}}' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c
```

Comment: ... because otherwise, `make` interprets `$0` as a reference to a variable named `0`, which it replaces with that variable's (empty) value.  The quoting in the command is meaningful to the shell, but not to `make`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I figured it was a pretty dumb mistake on my end.

Comment: @JediWolf: It's happened to everyone :-)

Comment: In `awk` `$0` is the default parameter for the test and actions when not specified. It can be simplified to `awk '!/#include "foobar.h"/' ../foo/foo.h >> bar.c`.